# SSIS PAckage ForEach Loop continue

Tags: error-handling, ssis, foreach-loop-container, dataflowtask

I have a ssis package which exports data from excel files and dump it into a SQL Table. For processing files, I am using a `foreach` loop and a dataflow opens an excel source and dumps data into ole db destination. If any file is not containing the required tab, I want the ssis package to log error and move to next iteration. I have tried following things but the package fails:

1. Propagation = false
2. ForceExecutionResult = Success

How can I handle this?

Attached images are the screen shots of control flow, data flow and progress.

[image: Data Flow]

[image: Progress]

Comment: you migt want to consider giving names to the images you attached

Answer (score 0):

Try on the For Each loop set maximum error count to 0 to ignore all errors.

In your for each loop have an on error sql script to write out if error so they are not lost.

Comment: in addition to your other steps above that is, do them as well they're right as well

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3575/continue-a-foreach-loop-after-an-error-in-a-sql-server-integration-services-package/ this is a good guide should help